# Use jQuery to get specific th tags with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [this](http://bit.ly/1qNNGDf) Bootstrap plugin for a work project (so yes, the code will be heavily censored when I put it here.)  The plugin takes JSON objects, (created in ColdFusion 10,) and puts them into HTML tables.

I basically have a table that has, separated, two columns that are just checkboxes, assigned and complete.  The plugin erases the contents of the th tags, ie `<th>Complete</th>` and puts a checkbox in that field.  The plugin creator has indicated that I'm basically on my own to solve this problem, using the example at the link given earlier.

So.  I've assigned ID tags to the th telements, ie `<th data-field="ASSIGNED" id="assigned" data-formatter="chkBoxFormatter" data-title="Assigned" data-align="center" data-valign="bottom" data-sortable="false" data-checkbox="true">Assigned</th>` and am trying to use jQuery to grab those elements, just the th box itself, leave the rows alone, so I can derp with this myself.  $("#assigned") doesn't work, and I'm wary of nth-child selectors and etc., because, if a subsequent developer rearranges the column order, it would break.  I'm hoping for a solution that is much harder for future developers to break.

FWIW, this is with the latest versions of jQuery and Bootstrap, with Modernizer loading into the browser but as of yet unused (I'm getting to it!)  I'm not opposed to adding jQueryUI, if it helps, but we're shying away from jQuery Mobile for reasons that are beyond the scope of this post.  Oh, and these are in  tags because the plugin requires it.

Yes, I've tried Googling, and reading the official jQuery docs, but the solutions presented are either ancient or seem too "brittle."

**TLDR version:** I want to select specific th tags and force text into them.

Comment: Reproduce the error in jsFiddle please.

Comment: What value does `$("#assigned").length` give you ?

Comment: `$("#assigned") ` - should always work provided that you have unique ids. Which is a must.

Comment: @TchiYuan console.log($("#assigned").length); prints 0

Comment: If you can't use unique ids, why not use attribute selectors? i.e. `$("th[attribute='property']")`

Comment: @entropic So $("th[id='assigned']"); ?

Comment: The plugin you linked doesn't *just* erase the contents of a `<th>`, it erases all HTML attributes. All I see in the DOM tree is `<th style>...</th>`

Comment: @iambriansreed Here's my hack at it, slightly abbreviated: http://jsfiddle.net/Muzical/6JLFG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Janet

Since `$("#assigned").length` returns 0 it means that the TH element doesn't exist at that moment.

You need to make sure that your table TH elements are already rendered.

In other words, at the moment when you need to use `$("#assigned")`, the th element you are looking for doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

Try this to see what you get:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log($("#assigned").length);
}, 5000);
```

The anonymous function will execute asynchronously in 5 seconds. Hopefully by then your TH will be rendered.

**EDIT:**

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JLFG/8/)

[image]

Comment: This still prints zero.

Comment: @Janet well then I really don't know but your problem is that your TH element definitely doesn't exist in your DOM at that moment when you do $("#assigned"). You'd need to setup a JSFiddle for us to help you more.

Comment: There's one printed in a comment on my original post.

Comment: Hi Janet, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JLFG/8/). It works for me. Your TH element with id "assigned" is found.

Comment: It works in IE and Firefox, but Chrome is entering the Not Found code.  This is probably risking spinning off into another question, but does Chrome do something different?

Comment: @Janet please check my answer for the screenshot I'm about to put in. You'll notice that I'm using Chrome.

Comment: So something's weird about my Chrome...reassuring.  Thank you, though ^_^

Comment: Make sure your clear your Chrome cache. When JSFiddle updates their web application, the old one is still cached in your Chrome browser.

Comment: I thought Ctrl F5 was doing enough on that, but I guess not.  I viewed it in incognito mode and it works.  Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

In HTML the id attribute is supposed to be unique.  So having multiple elements with the same ID is wrong.  One of a few options would be to use a unique class selector or adding your own unique attribute

```
<th class="my_assigned" data-field="ASSIGNED" data-formatter="chkBoxFormatter" data-title="Assigned" data-align="center" data-valign="bottom" data-sortable="false" data-checkbox="true">Assigned</th>
$('.my_assigned') ...
```

OR since it seems like those attributes are unique saying assigned any ways just piggy back on those.

```
<th data-field="ASSIGNED" id="assigned" data-formatter="chkBoxFormatter" data-title="Assigned" data-align="center" data-valign="bottom" data-sortable="false" data-checkbox="true">Assigned</th>
$('[data-field=ASSIGNED]') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the # selectors indicates a unique object id, that means, you should only have one th with the id="assigned".  By the other side, you can have many elements with the same class.

So, perhaps the solution would be to switch your "assigned" attributes to classes, like:

```
<th data-field="ASSIGNED" class="assigned" data-formatter="chkBoxFormatter" data-title="Assigned" data-align="center" data-valign="bottom" data-sortable="false" data-checkbox="true">Assigned</th>
```

beside that, you can select them by using

```
$('*[data-title="Assigned"]');
```